# reversing a list in racket using recursion-Racket

Tags: recursion, racket

this is my program for using recursion to reverse a list

```
(define l empty)
(define (reverse list)
  (cond
    [(empty? list)list]
    [((set! l(cons (car list) l))(reverse (cdr list)))])
   (display l))
(reverse '(1 2 3 4 ))
```

my program correctly giving the output '(4 3 2 1). but i also gives an error,
saying this application is not a procedier. 
I can't understand what is it..please tell me what have i done wrong

Comment: The `set!` is causing the "not a procedure" problem because it's returning `#<void>`. So my advice would be to start over and design it without using `set!`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that in racket, parentheses mean function application. "not a procedure" means "not a function," and it happens when you try to do a function call with something that's not a function. Here that's the `#<void>`, from the `set!`, causing that problem.

Comment: thanks for the help. thank you so much